# Draw Vertical lines on particular date in tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot vertical lines on particular dates. Tried this script below :

```
//@version=3
study("Vertical lines", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

plot((time == timestamp(2021,03,05,0,0)) ? 10e20 : na, 
      color = red, linewidth = 10, title = "27", style = histogram)

plot((time == timestamp(2021,03,01,0,0)) ? 10e20 : na, 
      color = green, linewidth = 10, title = "28", style = histogram)
```

This did not get the desired result. The indicator got plotted but did not see any vertical lines being plotted.

Would appreciate any help and thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script works without any errors. Vertical lines are displayed, but only for symbols that are traded 24 hours a day. Change the time so that it falls within the trading session of your symbol.

[image]

Comment: Can you guide me how to change time for trading session. This is the first time I am encountering this ?

Comment: in the `timestamp()` function, specify the hour and minutes

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked finally. Really appreciate your help and time. Thanks again.